# How do you dynamically change pivot items on a pivot table? (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic, pivot-table

How can I make a dynamic pivot table field?

The goal would be that the user could use data from a cell and ultimately change the data field item without having to press anything (ie if `A1` says `"Hello"`, it would de-select all other items in the data field and select the `"Hello"` data field item).

From recording my macro, to change my a pivot item in the pivot field I use the following code:

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Treaty].[Market Category].[Market Category]").VisibleItemList = Array("[Treaty].[Market Category].&[5Star Term]")

End Sub
```

I kept trying this solution from MrExcel and modified it to fit my own model:
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/543610-how-create-array-vba.html

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    MyArray = Application.Transpose(Range("A1").Value)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Treaty].[MarketCategory].&[Market Category]").VisibleItemsList = MyArray
End Sub
```

with the cell A1 having:

```
[Treaty].[Market Category].&[5Star Term]
```

Its not working. The Locals section on vba says that `MyArray` is picking it up but it says:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class.

What does this mean??

How can I fix this??

I looked at other solution on StackOverflow and I'm not getting what I want. Is there a way how to make the array dynamic?

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you sure you are working with the right sheet? Try changing activesheet for the actual sheet name containing the pivot and then use something like  Sheet1.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Treaty].[Market Category].[Market Category]").VisibleItemList = Array([A1])

Comment: Is this an OLAP based pivottable?

Comment: I'm positive its the correct sheet. Yes it is.

Comment: @QHarr can you please tell me what this means and how I can fix it

Comment: Why not just add a Slicer, and set it to the value you want?

Comment: and  lo the voice of reason appears.... great suggestion @jeffreyweir.